# Surefire 2.22.2 is not finding junit tests after removal of provider dependency

Tags: java, maven, junit, junit5, maven-surefire-plugin

First time posting! I've tried looking through all the other posts regarding surefire issues without any avail, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am currently trying to deal with the "junit-platform-surefire-provider has been deprecated" warning in my project. Version 2.22.2 of surefire is being used, where all of the junit jupiter tests in our project are currently found.

**WARNING:
The junit-platform-surefire-provider has been deprecated and is scheduled to
be removed in JUnit Platform 1.4. Please use the built-in support in Maven
Surefire >= 2.22.0 instead.
https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build-maven**

[Test results with 55 tests found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLbb7.png)

The issue arises when I try to remove the junit-platform-surefire-provider and jupiter-engine dependencies from within the plugin.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                    <version>1.3.2</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                    <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
        </plugin>
```

This provider is going to be deprecated and I am trying to get rid of it. I followed the documentation at https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build-maven in order to try and use the built in support in Maven Surefire. In addition to removing those two dependencies, I added the following two dependencies to my  section on my POM file.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Once I have done this, the build will complete, but it no longer finds any tests.

[Test Results with ZERO tests found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tocn.png)

Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: There’s a couple of things you’re doing wrong in your pom. Have a look at https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples/tree/master/junit5-jupiter-starter-maven.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

Had same issue on

- Maven 3.6.0
- Maven-surefire-plugin 2.22.2
- JUnit 5.7.0
- Java jdk 1.8.261

Added on pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.0</version>
    </dependency>    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.0</version>
   </dependency>
   <!--.... other dependencies -->
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!--.... other plugins -->
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Works fine and run all my test

Comment: Thank you it really saved me a lot of stress and time !!
BTW the junit-jupiter-api is not needed as its a dependency of junit-jupiter-engine

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, I needed to run Junit 4.12 tests a long with Junit 5. After I added the Junit 5 tests i got the next error:

```
[INFO]  T E S T S 16:28:24 [INFO]
------------------------------------------------------- 
16:28:26 [INFO]  
16:28:26 [INFO] Results: 
16:28:26 [INFO]  
16:28:26 [INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0 
16:28:26 [INFO]  
16:28:26 [INFO]
------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
16:28:26 [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS 
16:28:26 [INFO]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I read that adding

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

can fix my problem, but when I tried to run my tests I got next message

```
 [INFO]  T E S T S
    16:12:57 [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
    16:12:58 
    16:12:58  +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    16:12:58  | WARNING:                                                                      |
    16:12:58  | The junit-platform-surefire-provider has been deprecated and is scheduled to  |
    16:12:58  | be removed in JUnit Platform 1.4. Please use the built-in support in Maven    |
    16:12:58  | Surefire >= 2.22.0 instead.                                                   |
    16:12:58  | » https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build-maven |
    16:12:58  +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    16:12:58
```

finally next pom settings fixed it for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    .... More code here non relevant

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
      
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.0</version>
             <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
      
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

    .... More code here non relevant

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <dependenciesToScan>
                        <dependency>${group.id}:${test.project.name}</dependency>
                    </dependenciesToScan>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <inputEncoding>UTF-8</inputEncoding>
                    <outputEncoding>UTF-8</outputEncoding>
                    <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Now when I tried to run Junit 4.12 tests they were found, and executed.

---

### UPDATE

I have noticed some problem with log4j logs, which only showed exceptions stack traces. Also Junit5 stopped working. Hence after more testing my final version of the pom file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    .... More code here non relevant

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
      
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    .... More code here non relevant

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <dependenciesToScan>
                        <dependency>${group.id}:${test.project.name}</dependency>
                    </dependenciesToScan>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <inputEncoding>UTF-8</inputEncoding>
                    <outputEncoding>UTF-8</outputEncoding>
                    <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```